# How to install an Apple monitor on a Windows Vista PC?

Tags: windows, mac, windows-vista, display

I have an Apple display model M7478LL/A, and a desktop computer with Windows Vista and a Geforce 7100 video card. I connected the monitor to the PC and it does not turn on. I'm left with a black screen. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That old display had a special captive cable with 3 connectors: DVI, USB, and DC power (I believe the power connector was unique, not a standard). There was a disc-shaped external AC power adaptor that you had to plug the DC power connector into. Do you still have that power adaptor? Is it plugged in? Does this display work with any other machines?

**Update:** Your comment may have lost something in the translation, but the M7478LL/A display was one of the first displays to ever ship with a DVI connector in 1999, and it certainly didn't have an HDMI connector, because HDMI didn't really hit the market until 2003. This display was such an early first-generation DVI implementation that it might not be very interoperable with modern DVI video cards, and I wouldn't bother trying it with a DVI to HDMI adaptor.

It's possible that since it's such an early DVI implementation, that it doesn't signal its capabilities properly. You might be able to get your video card to work with it if you manually set your video card to one of the display's few supported resolutions:

- 1600 x 1024 (native resolution)
- 1280 x 800
- 1024 x 640
- 800 x 500

Also note these unusual resolutions -- its aspect ratio is 16:10 (1.6:1). If your video card doesn't support any of these 16x10 resolutions, it might not be compatible.

I can't find any Portuguese links to specifications for this display -- maybe Apple never shipped it in a Portuguese-speaking region? But here are some links in English that you can use Google Translate on.

[Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/specs/displays/Apple_Cinema_Display.html)
[User Manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/CinemaDisplay_22inchAbout.PDF)

**Google English -> Portuguese translation, unedited since I don't speak Portuguese:**
Essa demonstração de idade tinham um cabo especial em cativeiro com três conectores: DVI, USB e DC (acredito que o conector de alimentação era único, não uma norma). Havia um disco em forma de adaptador de energia AC externo que você tinha que ligar o conector de energia DC. Você ainda tem esse adaptador de energia? É conectado? Será que este monitor funciona com outros computadores?

**Atualização:** O seu comentário pode ter perdido alguma coisa na tradução, mas o M7478LL / A apresentação foi uma das primeiras exposições de sempre vêm com um conector DVI, em 1999, e que certamente não tem um conector HDMI, HDMI, porque não realmente chegar ao mercado até 2003. Esta exposição foi tão precoce da primeira geração de execução DVI que pode não ser muito compatíveis com placas de vídeo modernas DVI, e eu não me incomodaria de tentá-lo com um adaptador DVI-HDMI.

É possível que, uma vez que é como uma implementação DVI cedo, que não sinaliza as suas capacidades de forma adequada. Você pode ser capaz de obter a sua placa de vídeo para trabalhar com ele, se você configurar manualmente sua placa de vídeo é uma demonstração de algumas resoluções suportadas:

- 1600 x 1024 (resolução nativa)
- 1280 x 800
- 1024 x 640
- 800 x 500

Além disso, observe estas resoluções incomum - sua proporção é de 16:10 (1,6:1). Se sua placa de vídeo não suporta qualquer dessas resoluções 16x10, pode não ser compatível.

Eu não consigo encontrar nenhum link Português com as especificações para esta exposição - talvez nunca Apple embarcou em uma região de língua Português? Mas aqui estão alguns links em Inglês que você pode usar o Google Translate por diante.

[Especificações Técnicas](http://support.apple.com/specs/displays/Apple_Cinema_Display.html)
[Manual do Usuário](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/CinemaDisplay_22inchAbout.PDF)

Comment: tenho sim este disco e esta ligado. ele tem mesmo tres conectores: DI, USB e HDMI, comprei um adaptador DVI para HDMI e liguei no PC e nada da imagem. Eu levei o monitor a um amigo e liguei no computador mac dele e funcionou. no meu que windows vista nao quer funcionar.

Comment: @wekder I added some more information to my Answer. I hope this helps. [Eu adicionei mais algumas informações para a minha resposta. Espero que isso ajude.]